# writing values into csv file using single variable

Tags: c

I want to print the i value in csv file like i showed below output format.I can't find a way to write data to a new row in a .csv file using the C language.
I'm saving one variables to the .csv file, I want to display it row by row, I want output like

```
1,2
3,4
5,6
```

but it is displaying

```
1
2
3
4
5
6 etc.
```

my code is

```
    fp = fopen("testfile.csv","w");

    int i;
    for(i = 0 ; i < 100 ; i++)
    {               
        printf(" %d", i);
        fprintf(fp , "%d", i);
        fprintf(fp, "\n");
    }

    printf("\n");
    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your printing loop puts `\r\n` after each field, dropping it to the next line. You can replace that loop with something like:

```
fprintf(fp, "%d", a[0]);         // Output first value.
for (int i = 1; i < 6; ++i)
    fprintf(fp, ", %d", a[i]);   // Subsequent value prefixed with comma.
fprintf(fp, "\n");               // Finally, the line end.
```

That's assuming your six items should form a single row (as they did in your original question). If you want some other behaviour (like three rows of two), it's a minor change to do so, especially for a fixed size:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i += 2)
    fprintf(fp, "%d, %d", a[i], a[i+1]);
```

---

Better yet would be to hive that effort off to a function so you can call it from anywhere, with any set of data:

```
void outCsvInts(size_t sz, int *data, FILE *fp) {
    if (sz == 0) return;                // Zero size, no output.
    fprintf(fp, "%d", data[0]);         // Output first value.
    for (size_t i = 1; i < sz; ++i)
        fprintf(fp, ", %d", data[i]);   // Subsequent value with comma.
    fprintf(fp, "\n");                  // Line end.
}
```

Call that with:

```
outCsvInts(6, a, fp);
```

and it should do what you want (though you would be advised to use something *other* than the "magic" value `6`, using `sizeof`, for example).

And, with that method, it a lot easier to create a three-by-two output (as per your changed question), with (for small sets):

```
outCsvInts(2, &a[0], fp);
outCsvInts(2, &a[2], fp);
outCsvInts(2, &a[4], fp);
```

or (for larger sets):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 52; i += 2) // eg, 26 lines of two numbers each.
    outCsvInts(2, &a[i], fp);
```